# RubyTest has no output in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sublimetext2, ruby-test

I have RubyTest installed for Sublime Text 2, and when I try to run the tests within Sublime, once I see the log for what happened, this is what I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File "./exec.py", line 145, in run
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/myuser/code/ruby/movie_spec.rb'
reloading /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/RubyTest.last-run
Package Control: No updated packages
```

Any ideas? Rspec runs just fine when I use it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd recommend installing [ZenTest](https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest) and using its `autotest` functionality to continually run your tests in a terminal window.

It watches for changes in the tests and reruns them automatically. It's very handy as you write your code and tests.

Comment: Thanks for that - much appreciated. However, I am trying to mimic someone else's set up and would be ideal to use RubyTest